# XamlParseException in XAML

Tags: wpf, xaml

I'm trying to display some text from Resources in a TextBox. In my `Properties.Resources`, I have a string resource named `DefaultUrl`.

I'm using the following code to display it in the TextBox:

```
<Window x:Class="........"
    ...
    ...
    xmlns:properties="clr-namespace:project_name.Properties">

    <TextBox Text="{x:Static properties:Resources.DefaultUrl}"/>

</Window>
```

On building the project, it correctly displays the resource value in the TextBox, but on running the project, it gives me the following error:

> Exception thrown: 'System.ArgumentException' in System.Xaml.dll
>   Exception thrown: 'System.Xaml.XamlObjectWriterException' in System.Xaml.dll
>   Exception thrown: 'System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException' in PresentationFramework.dll
>
> 'Provide value on 'System.Windows.Markup.StaticExtension' threw an exception.' Line number '725' and line position '149'.

How can I display Properties.Resources string in XAML ??

Comment: Could you show how you define ``Properties.Resources``?

Comment: @CorentinPane I just go to `Project > project_name Properties > Resources` and create string resources

Comment: make sure that the access modifiers are set to public at Resources file

Comment: @styx the build action on the file is `EmbeddedResource`, Copy to output directory set to `Do not copy`. There's no setting for access modifier

Comment: Try to create a resource file (filename.resx) and set your strings there, there you will be able to set the access modifiers

Comment: There's an `Access Modifier` combo in a visual studio project resources editor.

Comment: Downvoters, care to explain ?

Answer (score 1):

**Solution:**

Going with @Max and @Styx comments, I was able to resolve this issue by changing the access modifier dropdown ( in Project resources ) value from `Internal` to `Public`